# Trying to pass function to child component React Native - Keep getting '...not a function' and '...undefined' errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, native

Trying to manage state between parent/child components in React Native. Using functional components and hooks. I want my Collection component (the parent) to be able to update state of an array after calling an onDelete function from the child. I keep tweaking the function but can't seem to get it to work. Thanks in advance!

Parent:

```
const Collection = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [showAddGuitar, setShowAddGuitar] = useState(false);
    const [gtrlist, setGtrlist] = useState(GUITARS);
    const [selectedGuitar, setSelectedGuitar] = useState({});

  // Open Details Page
    const openDetails = (guitar) => {
        setSelectedGuitar(guitar);
        navigation.navigate("Details", {
            id: guitar.id,
            year: guitar.year,
            brand: guitar.brand,
            model: guitar.model,
            sn: guitar.sn,
            description: guitar.description,
            history: guitar.history,
        });
    };

 // Delete Guitar
    const deleteGuitar = (id) => {
        setGtrlist(gtrlist.filter((guitar) => guitar.id !== id));
        console.log(gtrlist);
    };

    return (
        <View>
            {showAddGuitar && (
                <GuitarModal onAdd={addGuitar} onCloseModal={onCloseModal} />
            )}

            {gtrlist.length <= 0 && <Text>Collection empty</Text>}
            {gtrlist.length > 0 && (
                <FlatList
                    onDelete={deleteGuitar}
                    data={gtrlist}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <Text
                            style={styles.item}
                            onPress={() => openDetails(item)}
                        >
                            {item.year} {item.brand} {item.model}
                        </Text>
                    )}
                />
            )}
            <Button
                title="Add New Guitar"
                style={[styles.footer, styles.button, styles.buttonOpen]}
                onPress={handleAddNewGuitarPress}
            />
        </View>
```

Child:

```
  const DetailsPage = ({ route, navigation, onDelete }) => {
    const { id, year, brand, model, sn, description, history } = route.params;

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                {year} {brand} {model}
            </Text>
            <Text>S/N: {sn}</Text>
            <Text>Description: {description}</Text>
            {history &&
                history.map((item) => (
                    <Text key={item.id}>
                        {item.date} {item.item} {item.cost}
                    </Text>
                ))}
            <View>
                <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
                <Button
                    title="Delete guitar"
                    onPress={() => onDelete(id)}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: 1- I cannot see any "deleteGuitar" function anywhere in your parent. So it's undefined.
2 - You are not passing any function to DetailsPage

Comment: you should define `deleteGuitar` function on parent component.
`const deleteGuitar = (id) =>{//delete operation}`

Comment: Use react context or try recoil (https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/getting-started)
and share state, you could maybe try to pass onDelete over navigation params but I am not sure if that would work if parent gets unmounted somehow.

Comment: sorry folks! i messed up the cut and paste... deleteGuitar is in the code snippet now! my bad. :( @İlker

Comment: hmm but why are you passing it to flatlist?

Comment: @MarioLucki because the FlatList is re-rendering the list of guitars after one is deleted

Comment: @RenaissanceMan this property doesn't exist on FlatList according to documentation.

Comment: But you gotta know that DetailsPage is theoretically not a child component, it is rendered outside of the parent component if using react navigation. So I suggest you some state if your app is simple use react context.

Comment: You could try to add in params_: navigation.navigate("Details", { id: guitar.id, year: guitar.year, brand: guitar.brand, model: guitar.model, sn: guitar.sn, description: guitar.description, history: guitar.history, onDelete: deleteGuitar }); 


const { id, year, brand, model, sn, description, history,onDelete } = route.params;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't destructure onDelete from props since you don't pass the onDelete with props. Actually you don't pass it at all. While you passed other details with params, you can also pass onDelete functions with that as well.

```
 const openDetails = (guitar) => {
    setSelectedGuitar(guitar);
    navigation.navigate("Details", {
        id: guitar.id,
        year: guitar.year,
        brand: guitar.brand,
        model: guitar.model,
        sn: guitar.sn,
        description: guitar.description,
        history: guitar.history,
        deleteGuitar,

    });
};
```

then of course you need to destructure it on the DetailsPage. But I'm not quite sure what happens after you delete the guitar since you won't have details on that page.

Comment: IMO I think it would be better to use some shared state (React context) than passing deleteGuitar to it, you can never know what can happen to the "parent" component. It can unmount while navigating and deleteGuitar won't work.

Comment: well he said he wants to pass that function so.. I didn't want to go deeper than that

Comment: thank you all so much for the help with my noobie questions! sorry for my lack of understanding. i have done some reading just now on react context and it looks like a cool solution but i do still want to try and understand why i'm still getting these 'not a function' messages even when i pass the onDelete function as a parameter. i have tried passing both as parameter 'deleteGuitar' as well as 'onDelete: deleteGuitar' and then adding that to the route.params on the Details page. i must be doing something dumb because when i call the function from onPress I still get the same messages.

Comment: @RenaissanceMan did you destructure the function from params?

Comment: Ok, I finally got it working thanks to you @İlker and @MarioLucki! I followed the advice with passing function as parameter and destructuring and after discovering I had a dumb syntax error it is working now! Really appreciate the help! :D :D

Comment: @MarioLucki thanks for the headup and advice on React-context also! I will dig into it!

Comment: @RenaissanceMan also I would strongly suggest for you to use Typescript. Also for much simpler state management tool than context is zustand library. Happy coding